# Purpose of static storage duration variables in unnamed block/sope?

Tags: c, scope, static

I just saw some code like the following, containing unnamed blocks with local `static` variables or expression statements with local statics:

```
volatile uint8_t p = 1;
volatile uint8_t x = 0;

int main() {
    {
        static uint8_t l;
    }
    {
        static uint8_t l;
    }
    uint8_t y1 = ({static uint8_t l; if (p) {l = 0;} l;});    
    uint8_t y2 = ({static uint8_t l; if (p) {l = 0;} l;});    
    return y1 + y2;
}
```

I wonder what should be the purpose of declaring a variable `static` in such *unnamed* blocks?

I assume (not sure) that the local statics are distinct to each such block, but I can't reach it after leaving that block. Looking into the object file shows that they get distinct names in a common block.

(Please don't reason about the above code ... just to demo the use of `static`)

Comment: Limiting the scope of identifiers is generally good. This applies to statics too.

Comment: the first blocks are nonsense. You should ask about an *actual* use and we could explain.

Comment: You write “I just saw some code like the following,…” Quite possibly you have removed some contextual information that contains clues about why this was done. If nothing else, it could be the result of some preprocessing or automatic code generation that results in more useful code in other circumstances. To get a proper answer, you would need to show the original code and possibly provide additional information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The first 2 blocks are useless*. The next 2 lines are initializing. . It's a GCC extension thing known as compound statement.

#### Do we need to use static inside compound statement?

***No. You can use it without `static` too.***

Keep in mind one thing any temporary object that you create within `{}` those are destroyed when this statement ends. So they can't be used later also.
There is no use, using `static` inside the compound statement also. Simple `int` would do too.

Clearly the toy-code you have shown - those statics or even the compound list serves no purpose other than showing you that they can be used. Serving no purpose at all.All of this was to just `return 0`.

#### Extra points

Here `y1` and `y2` are intialized with the last statements value that is `l`. The result of `y1` and `y2`'s sum will be `0`.

From **[online documentation of `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)**

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression
>   followed by a semicolon; **the value of this subexpression serves as the
>   value of the entire construct**.

If you read through this document a bit you will see a line explaining its actual use

> This feature is especially useful in making macro definitions “safe”
>   (so that they evaluate each operand exactly once). For example, the
>   `maximum` function is commonly defined as a macro in standard C as
>   follows:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
  ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Unlike macro here the computes `a` and `b` once not twice like the other macro.

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```